# Codeigniter CLI As Daemon

Tags: linux, codeigniter, daemon, command-line-interface

I am creating a queue system where I need a set of workers to run jobs. For the queue I am planning on using Amazon's SQS. For my workers I would like to run instances of Codeigniter because the core application will also use Codeigniter and I would like to share the models of the workers with that of the core application.

I see that it is possible to hit a controller method using CI's CLI (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html). However, these workers should continually run, unless I kill them. I have looked into this article about setting up daemons using php: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/ This method requires that I use this class: https://github.com/kvz/system_daemon.

I am not sure if I should be calling and running System Daemon inside my controller in CI to spawn the entire CI instance as a daemon? Or is there a command-line approach where I can establish my call to the CI method as a daemon and then avoid using the 'System Daemon' class altogether? Any considerations I should be aware of? I have never created a running daemon, I have only used the cron tab to restart processes but that will not work in my case.

Comment: Wow this is a tumbleweed question I guess. so I guess the question could be summed up / simplified as "How can I run an instance of codeigniter as a daemon?"

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if anyone has daemonized properly codeigniter (I read that many had tried).
I had a similar situation with yours and I ended up using the System Daemon class which constantly checks SQS and then calling a CLI codeigniter via system() passing the message as a parameter.
My approach works for ~10 months without having any issues and serves ~30-40k messages per day.

Comment: Have you got any example code or a tutorial / write up on how to implement this? Thanks